# Python : I need help generating lists of numbers in a specific format

Tags: python, math, numbers

I'm having trouble generating lists of numbers with the following parameters:

1. User specified number of digits
2. One number repeated
3. Create all possible combinations with this pattern

Ideally, I would like my output to be similar to this

```
list = [1123, 1213, 1231, 1223, 1232, 1233]
```

but for any amount of digits.

Thank you!

Update:

**Input**

```
digits = 5
```

**Output**

```
output = [11234, 12134, 12314, 12341, 12234, 12324, 12342, ... ]
```

I know it isn't a lot to go on, I'm sorry. I need all possible combinations of x digits such that the numbers 1 to x-1 appear in each entry and for every entry there is one digit repeated. You could think about it as if the repeated number travels all the way right before the next unique integer is repeated.

Comment: An example input might be more concise, can you provide ?

Comment: can u give input and expected output ?

Comment: Is your example output for `4` digits complete? Why is `1132` not included? What about `2123`? You need to be more clear in your desired output. Also, what work have you done on this problem and just where are you stuck? Please show us some attempted code on your part.

Comment: yes his op for 4 digits is complete.he want to add number in sequence.The greater number should be in right side except the repeated one.Check my solution and output too for 4 digit @RoryDaulton

Comment: @sachindubey: I do see a pattern in that first example output list, but *the questioner* needs to make that pattern clear. He even needs to make it clear that the example output is complete. We should not reward such laziness from questioners who show no work of their own and do not even bother to explain the problem fully. The last edit to the question still leaves out some important details--it does not explain why `2123` is not in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really pythonic solution but i found that one.You can take digit as a input from user.

```
digit = 5
list = []
val = []
temp = []
for i in range(1,digit):
    i = str(i)
    val.append(i)
    temp.append(i)
for i,num1 in enumerate(val):
    for j, num2 in enumerate(val):
        if int(i) <= int(j):
            temp.insert(int(j+1),num1)
            list.append("".join(temp))
            temp = []
            for k in range(1,digit):
                k = str(k)
                temp.append(k)
result = map(int,list) # Convert all element of list to int
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[11234, 12134, 12314, 12341, 12234, 12324, 12342, 12334, 12343, 12344]
```

Comment: Pythonic or not, this is perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

Give specified number `n`:

1. Create every combination with numbers `1 to n+1`.
2. A `for` loop from `1` to `n` that replace `n+1` with the for loop variable `i`.
3. Use `a = list(set(a))` to get rid of repeated combination.

Hope this pseudo code can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `itertools.permutations`.

`permutations('123')` would give you all possible numbers that can be generated with digits 1,2,3, but in tuple format.

```
list(permutations('123'))
[('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '3', '2'), ('2', '1', '3'), ('2', '3', '1'), ('3', '1', '2'), ('3', '2', '1')]
```

So you can do something like

```
from itertools import permutations, chain
n=3
tpls = [permutations(chain([i], range(1,n)), n) for i in range(1, n)]
# tpls contains all possible answers in tuple format

# To convert it to list of numbers
f = lambda t: int(''.join(map(str, t)))
[f(x) for x in chain(*tpls)]
# [112, 121, 112, 121, 211, 211, 212, 221, 122, 122, 221, 212]
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton. Good catch.. Updated the answer